# I am getting NODE.JS Error: Write EPIPE how to fix?

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

So i am developing a music discord bot and when i try to play a song, i got an error. I don't know what EPIPE is but it is there. Im using Discord.JS v12, latest NODE.JS, and im using module ytdl-core. This is the error:

```
    Error: write EPIPE
    at WriteWrap.onWriteComplete [as oncomplete] (internal/stream_base_commons.js:94:16) {
  errno: -32,
  code: 'EPIPE',
  syscall: 'write'
}
```

This is the code from the music part like play, skip, stop and then the functions:

```
       } else if(command === 'play'){
           execute(message, serverQueue);
       } else if(command === 'skip'){
           skip(message, serverQueue);
       } else if(command === 'stop'){
           stop(message, serverQueue);
       }
   });

   async function execute(message, serverQueue) {
     const args = message.content.split(" ");

     const voiceChannel = message.member.voice.channel;
     if (!voiceChannel)
       return message.channel.send(
         "You need to be in a voice channel to play music!"
       );
     const permissions = voiceChannel.permissionsFor(message.client.user);
     if (!permissions.has("CONNECT") || !permissions.has("SPEAK")) {
       return message.channel.send(
         "I need the permissions to join and speak in your voice channel!"
       );
     }

     const songInfo = await ytdl.getInfo(args[1]);
     const song = {
           title: songInfo.videoDetails.title,
           url: songInfo.videoDetails.video_url,
      };

     if (!serverQueue) {
       const queueContruct = {
         textChannel: message.channel,
         voiceChannel: voiceChannel,
         connection: null,
         songs: [],
         volume: 5,
         playing: true
       };

       queue.set(message.guild.id, queueContruct);

       queueContruct.songs.push(song);

       try {
         var connection = await voiceChannel.join();
         queueContruct.connection = connection;
         play(message.guild, queueContruct.songs[0]);
       } catch (err) {
         console.log(err);
         queue.delete(message.guild.id);
         return message.channel.send(err);
       }
     } else {
       serverQueue.songs.push(song);
       return message.channel.send(`${song.title} has been added to the queue!`);
     }
   }

   function skip(message, serverQueue) {
     if (!message.member.voice.channel)
       return message.channel.send(
         "You have to be in a voice channel to stop the music!"
       );
     if (!serverQueue)
       return message.channel.send("There is no song that I could skip!");
     serverQueue.connection.dispatcher.end();
   }

   function stop(message, serverQueue) {
     if (!message.member.voice.channel)
       return message.channel.send(
         "You have to be in a voice channel to stop the music!"
       );
       
     if (!serverQueue)
       return message.channel.send("There is no song that I could stop!");
       
     serverQueue.songs = [];
     serverQueue.connection.dispatcher.end();
   }

   function play(guild, song) {
     const serverQueue = queue.get(guild.id);
     if (!song) {
       serverQueue.voiceChannel.leave();
       queue.delete(guild.id);
       return;
     }

     const dispatcher = serverQueue.connection
       .play(ytdl(song.url))
       .on("finish", () => {
         serverQueue.songs.shift();
         play(guild, serverQueue.songs[0]);
       })
       .on("error", error => console.error(error));
     dispatcher.setVolumeLogarithmic(serverQueue.volume / 5);
     serverQueue.textChannel.send(`Start playing: **${song.title}**`);
   }
```

How can i fix it? Im new to this so i dont know... I've tried to reinstall everything, delete node_modules folder but nothing worked. Please help.